# solr index empty although schema browser shows entries

Tags: solr

I have a very strange problem: I am indexing documents without any problems.

When i go to the solr backend and search I get no results although in the schema browser I see that documents got indexed. Any idea what went wrong?

The `hidden_b` flag is set to `false`.

All helpful answers are appreciated.

Comment: how are you querying? can we see your schema.xml?

Comment: /select/?q=*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

Comment: i didn`t change the schema.xml - i just added some dynamic fields.

Comment: look up your fields in the administration, pick one out and use following query "yourField:*". do you get any results?

Comment: yes - it seems like all data is here - ok thanks a lot! I guess there is just a problem with showing all data.

Answer (score 1):

```
/select/?q=*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

this is your comment, but this actually doesn't work, the correct way to have all documents is this

```
/select/?q=*:*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

notice the

```
*:*
```

instead of

```
*
```

as your q parameter. it means "search against any field for any value" (equivalent to SELECT * FROM TABLE in mysql)

using only a * brings you no results.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a problem with the configuration in your schema.xml. I suppose your default search field doesn´t contain any data. You have to copy the contents of the other fields to your default search field. Therefor I would suggest you to define a field just for searching the whole content. For example:

```
<field name="searchfield" type="mySearchField" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

after that, your change the default search field, in this case like that:

```
<defaultSearchField>searchfield</defaultSearchField>
```

The last thing you have to do is this:

```
<copyField source="anyfieldfromyours" dest="searchfield"/>
```

Make sure you defined the type I used for this example and that you copy all of your fields. If you have just a dynamic field, you just have to copy this field.

Best regards